# Pre compile amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp for Raspberry pi 2

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, compilation, raspberry-pi

i've a Raspberry pi 2 with the Amazon Kinesis Stream SDK (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp) correctly running on board.

The compilation of the library was too long on the Raspberry pi 2, about 3H.

So the question, is there a way to pre-compile this library on a more powerful server and then copy the files on the Raspberry?

If it's possible i'd like to try this library also on Raspberry Pi Zero W (smaller in terms of size).

The installer instructions are here https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/blob/master/install-instructions-linux.md

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider cross compiling your library - for example on a Linux PC. Cross compiling is very common. Think about App development targeting phones. You don't compile your code on the phone. You cross compile on a Mac or PC and then push your executable to the phone.
You can do the same with Raspberry Pi. Here are a couple links:

https://medium.com/@au42/the-useful-raspberrypi-cross-compile-guide-ea56054de187
https://hackaday.com/2016/02/03/code-craft-cross-compiling-for-the-raspberry-pi/
https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/crosscompiler/